# problems with adapter + threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

```
W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

This is my problem. I'm trying to create a chat, for that I'm using a RecyclerView and Sockets, keep in mind that I have to use sockets (part of the homework). So I open a connection and start a thread to listen for the Server, which will send me a msg everytime any chat participant sends a msg. I'm using an AsyncTask in which I conenct to the server, thats needed cus I can't peform connections on main thread.

In the end I'm doing some kind of recursion, connect to the server, wait for a msg, disconnect, execute an onPostExecute to change the itens and call AsyncTask again.

The problem is  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); isnt doing what Ive spected, itens on my RecyclerView doesnt change or when it does it load all the Recycler again.

I have the onCreate of the activity, which have the normal stuff + Recyclye initializer, and then I call:

```
private void conAtualizer() {
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread Thread = new HandlerThread("Handler") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socketMsg = Conection.persistentConect();
                DataOutputStream outToServer = 
                        new DataOutputStream(socketMsg.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader servidorAnsw = 
                        new BufferedReader(new 
                                InputStreamReader(socketMsg.getInputStream()));
                outToServer.writeBytes("406" + '\n' + 
                        getIntent().getStringExtra("LOGED_ID")+"\n"+
                        getIntent().getStringExtra("TARGET_ID") + '\n');

                newMsg=false;
                while(active){
                    if(servidorAnsw.ready()){
                        if(servidorAnsw.readLine().equals("406")){
                            MetaMessage thisMetaMessage = 
                                    new MetaMessage(servidorAnsw.readLine());
                            menssages.add(thisMetaMessage);
                            newMsg=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                outToServer.writeBytes("close\n");
                latch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread.start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the notify:

```
public class NotConv extends AsyncTask <String,Void,MetaMnssage>{

    @Override
    protected MetaMessage doInBackground(String... params) {
        while(!newMsg){
        }
        if(ative){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MetaMessage thisMetaMessage) {
        newMsg=false;
        new NotConv().execute("");
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `runOnUIThread`.

Comment: I can't perform a connection on the main thread. `runOnUIThread` runs on the main thread.

Comment: you should post your code here, so every1 can help.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the main post

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify where the error occurs.

But from the error itself I can understand that you are trying to update UI views from a background process (Meaning a Thread or something that runs on a different one than the UI Main thread).

As people suggested, you should use runOnUiThread() in your thread only whenever you need to update a view.

Also why do you perform notifyDataSetChanged() in donInBackground() ? You may need to consider do that on onPreExecute() or onProgressUpdate() which should be used to make UI changes.

Comment: This is the solution Ive made to go around the error.

Comment: I was trying to update the adapter at the conAtualizer() method, which generated that error. conAtualizer keeps running, waiting for a new msg from the server, it doesnt run in the main thread. But NotConv I call in the main thread, and it will be in loop until I receive a new msg at conAtualizer and the the variable newMsg to true which will stop the while loop, notify the adapter and run the onPostExecute to start another loop.